# Чего не хватает Cygwin для компиляции (C++)?

Tags: c++, компиляция, cygwin

Компилирую C++ в Cygwin под Windows7:

```
$ make -f makefile.unix
/bin/sh ../share/genbuild.sh obj/build.h
g++ -c -O2 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -g -DUSE_IPV6 -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -I/home/Vincent/Projects/FOLDER/src -I/home/Vincent/Projects/FOLDER/src/obj -DUSE_UPNP=0 -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -fno-stack-protector -fstack-protector-all -Wstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -MMD -MF obj/checkpoints.d -o obj/checkpoints.o checkpoints.cpp
In file included from bignum.h:13:0,
                 from main.h:9,
                 from checkpoints.cpp:11:
util.h:134:51: ошибка: «va_list» не был декларирован
 std::string vstrprintf(const std::string &format, va_list ap);
                                                   ^
makefile.unix:138: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «obj/checkpoints.o»
make: *** [obj/checkpoints.o] Ошибка 1
```

Под Linux тот же код скомпилился без ошибок, т.е. проблема не в коде точно.

Answer (score 1):

`#include <stdarg.h>` или `#include <cstdarg>` должно помочь...

Comment: добавил `#include <cstdarg>` в файл `util.h` - теперь выдает кучу предупреждений и вот такую ошибку:

`In file included from bignum.h:13:0,
                 from main.h:9,
                 from db.h:9,
                 from main.cpp:8:
main.cpp: В функции «void BitcoinMiner(CWallet*)»:
util.h:604:41: ошибка: нет декларации «PRIO_MAX» в этой области видимости
 #define THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST          PRIO_MAX
                                         ^
main.cpp:3640:23: замечание: in expansion of macro «THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST»
     SetThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST);`

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос и, скорее всего, вопрос к авторам майнера.